# Does PY2EXE Compile a Python Code to run Faster?

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I really like the PY2EXE module, it really helps me share scripts with other co-workers that are super easy for them to use.

My question is: when the PY2EXE module compiles the code into an executable, does the resulting executable process faster?

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: Have you tried timing it? :-)

Comment: Not any faster than running compiled python I'd imagine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

py2exe just bundles the Python interpreter and all the needed libraries into the executable and a few library files. When you run the executable, it uses the bundled interpreter to run your script.

Since it doesn't actually generate native code, the speed of execution should be about the same, possibly slower because of the overhead of everything being packaged up.

Comment: I did some tests and it seems you are correct. PY2EXE still is great for its ability to compile python to run on any computer, but I was really hoping it would speed up the code as well. Oh well, I guess I'll try cython next!

Comment: @CodyBrown - you should check what is actually slow in your code. Libs like numpy use very well optimised C for the actual operations and are often faster than the C code you could write yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Partly, it bundles the python environment with the 'precompiled' pyc files. These are already 
parsed into python byte code but they aren't native speed executables

Comment: Note that just importing the code does exactly the same compilation to bytecode. Even if it didn't, you'd only win some (definitely very little, the compiler is fast) startup time because then the same compilation would occur when the source code is parsed.

Comment: @delnan, yes it's a very small win - that's why I said 'partly'